# The dimension of open subschemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be an integral scheme. Assume there exists a morphism of finite type from $X$ to the spectrum of a field. Is the Krull dimension of any non-empty open $U\subset X$ (possibly non-affine) equal to the Krull dimension of $X$?

Some hypotheses are necessary here (consider the generic point of the spectrum of a DVR, for example).

Comment: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4200/flood-of-similar-new-users

Comment: Tag [0A21](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0A21)(3)

Comment: @ToddTrimble Dear Todd Trimble, could you please not these link this discussion to my questions? I am a different person from whomever is the cardinal and I do not see how you linking this here is helpful. Besides, could you please reply to my criticism of your answer there? I think that you reply to the comments of other people (e.g. Yemon Choi) reasonably quickly, yet you ignore my comments for some reason.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn thank you very much Remy! That would qualify as answer too, you can post it.

Comment: Thanks for confirming your identity! Since my time is limited, I choose on a case by case basis whether to respond to comments of people who I think are not acting in good faith. Maybe you can ask Community Management to look into your questions?